# std::copy failure, "cannot seek vector iterator after end"

Tags: c++, stdvector

I put together this test case that reproduces the conditions and problem I'm getting in larger code.  I do in fact need to copy from a C array of POD structures, but I'd like the destination to be a vector so it can handle the copy deletion on its own.

```
TEST_METHOD(std_copy)
{
    struct W { long a; int b; char c; char d; };
    W block[1] = { { 15, 42, 'D', 'X' } };
    std::vector<W> dest;
    dest.reserve(1);
    std::copy(block, block+1, dest.begin());
    Assert::AreEqual(42, dest[0].b);
}
```

The assertion "cannot seek vector iterator after end" seems to be occurring within the `dest.begin()` call, which makes no sense to me.  I'm sure I'm just missing an obvious detail, but what is it?

Comment: `std::vector::reserve()` only changes capacity not vector size

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the error message said, you're getting out of the bound of the vector.

Given `std::copy(block, block+1, dest.begin());`, `dest` is supposed to contain at least the same number of elements (i.e. one element here), but it's empty in fact.

You can use `resize` instead of `reserve`,

```
std::vector<W> dest;
dest.resize(1);
std::copy(block, block+1, dest.begin());
```

Or just

```
std::vector<W> dest(1);
std::copy(block, block+1, dest.begin());
```

Or use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to get an [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).

> The container's `push_back()` member function is called whenever the iterator (whether dereferenced or not) is assigned to.

```
std::vector<W> dest;
dest.reserve(1);
std::copy(block, block+1, std::back_inserter(dest));
```

Comment: Or `v.insert(v.end(), block, block+1)`

Comment: dest is supposed to contain *at least* the same number

Comment: or simply construct `dest` from `block` like: `std::vector<W> dest{ std::begin(block), std::end(block) };`

Comment: Thanks @songyuanyao (and @Slava), I was missing the distinction between `resize()` and `reserve()`.

Comment: @JeJo that would be the best, but in the original context, the size of the input block is not available at compile time; it's known through a separate variable.